# Desktop Sharing from browser

Tags: screensharing, desktop-sharing

I want to ask a question that if there is any library or thing that allow desktop sharing from browser, i am not asking about screen-sharing (i.e a browser page through webrtc) i am asking about desktop sharing (like teamviewer) means other user can use your computer from his browser and the other person is getting whole screen of your computer not just a particular tab.

if your answer is it cannot be done because JS will loaded in a particular tab then can it be possible by using some small app that transfer screen data/video bytes to browser and then it sent to the other person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is : WebRTC
Following these links:

- Firefox Extension (sample) : http://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/

  > > Add your *. to about:config -> getUserMedia screensharing allowed domains
- Google Chrome extension (sample) : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search

  > > Open this in Run : Chrome.exe --enable-usermedia-screen-capturing
- Other Reference : https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment

Answer (score 0):

There has not been a way to do this, mainly due to (i believe) Chrome's sandboxing, and, well, other browser's sandboxes and security features. If you are targeting Windows, you could do an ActiveX script or do something with Flash or Air.

Comment: But Chrome has a Remote Desktop Addon from Google that give access to Desktop therefore there should have to be any way.

Comment: I'm not an expert in reaching out of the browser. I don't think I can help you right now.

Comment: @Shah92 At least, you can enable Firefox about:config preferences (flags) using an addon (extension) : https://github.com/muaz-khan/Firefox-Extensions